# Exception in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hello im doing little CRUD, and without WEB layer all works.. And now i attached Spring MVC and it doesn't want to work. I'm trying to deploy app into Tomcat, and getting this Exception. Can't understand why.. Please help.
Thank you.

```
INFO  ContextLoader [ContextLoader.java:347] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7470 ms
INFO  DispatcherServlet [FrameworkServlet.java:488] FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:510] Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Nov 29 23:35:33 EET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader [XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:317] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/spring-mvc.xml]
WARN  XmlWebApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:487] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/SynthesizingMethodParameter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667) [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633) [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681) [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552) [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493) [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/64925031.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/SynthesizingMethodParameter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:857) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1282) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.<clinit>(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:76) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.SynthesizingMethodParameter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
ERROR DispatcherServlet [FrameworkServlet.java:501] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/SynthesizingMethodParameter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/64925031.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/SynthesizingMethodParameter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:857) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1282) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.<clinit>(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:76) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.SynthesizingMethodParameter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
[2015-11-29 11:35:34,806] Artifact TimeManager:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-11-29 11:35:34,806] Artifact TimeManager:war exploded: Deploy took 11 610 milliseconds
```

Web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>My app</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/spring-app.xml
            classpath:spring/spring-db.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Spring-mvc.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
               xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="ua.myapps.**.web"/>


<!--  all resources inside folder src/main/webapp/resources are mapped so they can be referred to inside JSP files -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp"/>
</beans>
```

Spring-app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

       <context:annotation-config/>
       <context:component-scan base-package="ua.myapps.timemanager.service"/>

</beans>
```

Spring-db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

       <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/postgres.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

       <tx:annotation-driven/>

       <bean id="dataSource"
             class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
             p:url="${database.url}"
             p:driverClassName="${database.driverClassName}"
             p:username="${database.username}"
             p:password="${database.password}"
               />

       <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
             p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
             p:packagesToScan="ua.myapps.timemanager.model">

           <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
               <map>
                   <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).FORMAT_SQL}" value="${hibernate.format_Sql}"/>
                   <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).USE_SQL_COMMENTS}" value="${hibernate.user_sql_comments}"/>
               </map>
           </property>

           <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
               <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                       p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}">
               </bean>
           </property>
       </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
              p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>



    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.myapps.timemanager.repository.datajpa"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="ua.myapps.timemanager.repository.datajpa"/>

</beans>
```

Dont know why it happens, please help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SynthesizingMethodParameter` was only introduced in [Spring 4.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/SynthesizingMethodParameter.html). If you're using Maven you can use the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Omg it works! Thank you.
It happened because Spring Data in Maven was first (with old Core) and Spring MVC was second (with new Core). So maven took old version of core)

Comment: Hmm.. Where can it be used ? I mean SynthesizingMethodParameter. 
Because earlier all worked fine, without it, does some dependency use it now ?

Comment: From [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.html) the class is used internally by Spring. BTW _all_ of your Spring dependencies should be the same version :)