# Please advice to me that Spring MVC Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I don't know what went wrong.

I'll attach the sources and advice to me why the error is happening..

pom.xml

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

that is error code

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error loading DispatcherServlet's default strategy class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver] for interface [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/SynthesizingMethodParameter
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:830)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerExceptionResolvers(DispatcherServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:476)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet$ContextRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1121)
    at
```

I don't know why I get an error.

please let me know how to fix the problem.

Comment: I think this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988668/exception-in-spring-mvc) should help you. You need to add spring core to dependencies.

Comment: I also have that dependency. but my pom.xml have spring-core version is 4.1.6.. I modify version it is work. Is there a difference between the different versions?

Comment: yes, `SynthesizingMethodParameter` was only introduced in Spring 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `NoClassDefFoundError`and I suppose that you did not include `spring-core`. Below is the missing dependency that should be added to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I also have that dependency. but my pom.xml have spring-core version is 4.1.6.. I modify version. and it is work. Is there a difference between the different versions?

Comment: Yes it is. This class `SynthesizingMethodParameter` from the error was only added in version 4.2.

Comment: If the issue was solved - could you check this question as answered in order not to paste more answers for you as this question stays open for now :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a dependency to spring-core in your pom.xml. The fragment below should fix your issue:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I also have that dependency. but my pom.xml have spring-core version is 4.1.6.. I modify version it is work. Is there a difference between the different versions?

Comment: Apparently there is... You can check the change logs if you have time for that. If I have to throw a guess that class must have been changed or introduced after 4.1.6